# Proof inequality for all positive numbers

Tags: inequality, roots

How to prove this inequality: it started with

prove:

$\sqrt {ab} \geqslant \frac {2} {1/a+1/b} $  for all positive numbers on $a$ and $b$. Leftside = rightside when $a=b$.

I could make it until:

$\sqrt a \cdot \sqrt b \geqslant \frac {2ab} {b+a} $

this is as far as I could go, I don't know how to prove it further.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)  $\dfrac{a+b}2\ge\sqrt{ab}$

Comment: you are basically done. $\frac {2ab} {b+a}= \frac{2}{\frac{b+a}{ab}}= \frac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}$

Comment: The last step is equivalent to $a+b\ge 2\sqrt{ab}$, and it's an inequality that a square number is at least zero.

Comment: thanks @J.W.Tanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove that

$1)\quad\sqrt{ab}\geqslant\dfrac2{\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b}\;$  for all positive real numbers $\,a\,$ and $\,b\;.$

$2)\quad\sqrt{ab}=\dfrac2{\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b}\;\iff\;a=b\;.$

**Proof :**

First we will prove the inequality $\;1)\;.$

For all positive real numbers $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,,\,$ it results that

$\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{ab}\cdot\color{blue}{\dfrac{a+b}{b+a}}\geqslant\sqrt{ab}\cdot\color{blue}{\dfrac{a+b-\left(\sqrt a-\sqrt b\right)^2}{b+a}}=$

$\!\qquad=\sqrt{ab}\cdot\dfrac{2\sqrt{ab}}{b+a}=\dfrac{2ab}{b+a}=\dfrac2{\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b}\quad,$

hence ,

$\sqrt{ab}\geqslant\dfrac2{\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b}\;$  for all positive real numbers $\,a\,$ and $\,b\;.$

Now we will prove the equivalence $\;2)\;.$

$\sqrt{ab}=\dfrac2{\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b}\;\iff\;\dfrac{a+b}{b+a}=\dfrac{a+b-\left(\sqrt a-\sqrt b\right)^2}{b+a}\;\iff$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\,\iff\;\left(\sqrt a-\sqrt b\right)^2=0\;\iff\;a=b\quad,$

hence ,

$\sqrt{ab}=\dfrac2{\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b}\;\iff\;a=b\;.$

Answer (score 2):

You've arrived at $$\sqrt{ab} \geqslant \frac{2ab}{a + b}.$$
The above is equivalent to $$1 \geqslant \frac{2\sqrt{ab}}{a + b}$$ or $$a + b \geqslant 2\sqrt{ab}.$$
Rearranging gives $$\left(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}\right)^2 \geqslant 0.$$ Can you finish it now?

Comment: Thank you very much! I can finish it using the rearranged version, only part I don't understand is how to do go from $$a + b \geqslant 2\sqrt{ab}.$$ to $$\left(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}\right)^2 \geqslant 0.$$

Comment: Never mind I just understood I needed to use some formula, it's solved now! thanks a ton!! @Aryaman Maithani